# Calling WCF web service using ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, web-services

I'm trying to call a webservice method GetUserLandingPage(username,password) using jquery ajax.
Here is my code

```
    var userName=$("#txt_userName").val().trim();
    var password=$("#txt_userPassword").val().trim();

    var data={
    "username":userName,
    "password":password
    };
    var jsonData=JSON.stringify(data);
    $.ajax({
    url: "http://www.coolcomma.com/user.svc/GetUserLandingPage",
    type:"GET",
    data:jsonData,
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    crossDomain : true,
    success: function(result){
        alert(result);
    }
});
```

When i'm running the page in browser 400 Bad request error is occuring.Any idea what is my problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the Authorization header in your call. Just converting the username and password data to json is not correct. You need to base64 encode your string at first. And in the ajax call to this.

(The base64Encodedstring should be "username:password")

```
$.ajax({
    headers : {
     "Authorization" : "Basic base64Encodedstring"
    },
    type: "GET",
    xhrFields: {
        withCredentials : true
    },
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success : function(data) {
        console.log("ok!");
    },
    error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(textStatus + ' | ' + errorThrown);
    }
});
```

Also, check out this url: http://sameproblemmorecode.blogspot.se/2011/10/creating-secure-restfull-wcf-service.html